# Converter peso em dinheiro

Tags: java

Eu estou tentando converter peso em dinheiro, mas toda vez a minha resposta é zero e eu calculei aqui e nn devia dar zero kkkkk algm pode me ajudar obs: o 5 é o preço por quilo
(Esse trabalho irá fazer eu passar de série me deem um help pf kkkkk)

```
private void convertButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                                              

    double pesagem = Double.parseDouble(peso.getText());
    double Result = ((5/1000)*pesagem);
    textresult.setText("R$ "+Result);
}
```

Comment: Peso em dinheiro? Que conversão é essa? Edite a pergunta ai, está bastante dificil entender.

Comment: O programa é para uma gelateria onde o funcionario digita o peso do sorvete e o software calcular e transforma em dinheiro de acordo com o preço por kilo

Comment: Então, edite a pergunta e passe mais detalhes sobre o que está fazendo(como fez nos comentarios), senão fica dificil entender o problema.

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 5):

Quando você utiliza um `int` em uma divisão o resultado será arredondado. Portanto para resolver o seu problema, altere o cálculo do resultado para:

```
double Result = ((5.0 / 1000.0) * pesagem);
```

**Dica:** Não use variáveis iniciando com letra maiúscula para respeitar a convenção de nomenclatura **Java**. Use da seguinte forma:

```
double result = ((5.0 / 1000.0) * pesagem);
```